# Spring Security - cannot to change default login page to custom

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am learning a Spring Security.

Now I want to customize login page, but I can't to change default page to custom.
In the security config I written loginPage("/login"), created controller, but this steps didn't help me.

My configuration class:

```java
package configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/resources/templates/**", "/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .disable();
  }
}
```

Controller:

```java
package controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class AuthController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLoginPage() {
        return "login";
    }
}
```

Path to login.html: `resources/templates/login.html`

login.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Login page</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
          href="../static/style.css" th:href="@{style.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<header align="center">
    <ul>
        <a class="logo" href="home.html"><span>L</span><span>O</span><span>G</span><span>O</span></a>
    </ul>
</header>
<div class="content_div">
    <div class="div_c">
        <div class="content_reg">
            <form method="post">
                <h1 class="form_title">Registration</h1>
                <div class="form_group">
                    <input type="email" class="form_input" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form_label">E-mail</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form_group">
                    <input type="text" class="form_input" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form_label">Login</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form_group">
                    <input type="password" class="form_input" placeholder=" ">
                    <label class="form_label">Password</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="form_button">Register</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div_c">
        <form action="/login" class="login_form" method="post">
            <h1 class="form_title">Log in</h1>
            <div class="form_group">
                <input type="text" class="form_input" placeholder=" ">
                <label class="form_label">Login</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form_group">
                <input type="password" class="form_input" placeholder=" ">
                <label class="form_label">Password</label>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="form_button">Log in</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you help me with this problem - I'll be very thankful.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're seeing and how that differs from the expected behaviour? What happens when you directly access `localhost:8080/login`?

Answer (score 0):

Your login page seems to be working fine on path "/login", if you want unauthenticated requests to be redirected to /login you should delete `disable()` from `WebSecurityConfig`

Comment: No, I want to change the default login page to a custom one, but for some reason the default page is constantly being opened. Although, it would seem, I changed it to a custom one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Spring where to look for your static files:

```
spring.web.resources.static-locations=classpath:/META-INF/resources/,classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/,classpath:/public/,classpath:/resources/templates/
```

You can read more about this at https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources#2-custom-directories.